# How you can save appends to variables an then convert them to php so you can save them in a database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Test page for Query YQL</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://hail2u.github.io/css/natural.css">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://hail2u.github.io/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test page for Query YQL</h1>

  <div id="content"></div>

  <input type="button" name="bt1" value="click" onclick="pesquisa()">

  <form name="s2">
    <input type="text" name="s1">
  </form>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.query-yql.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function pesquisa(){

      $(function () {

        var t = $('#content').empty();
        var url= document.s2.s1.value;
        var statement = 'select * from feed where url="'+url+'"';

        $.queryYQL(statement, function (data) {
          $('<h2/>').text('Test: select * from feed').appendTo(t);
          var r = data.query.results;
          var ul = $('<ul/>');

          $.each(r.item, function () {  

            $('<li/>').append(this.title).appendTo(ul);
            $('<li/>').append(this.link).appendTo(ul);

            <?php

              $titulo = "<script>document.write(titulo);</script>";

              $site = "<script>document.write(site);</script>";

              //echo $titulo;
              //echo  $site;

            ?>
          });
          ul.appendTo(t);
        });
      });
    };

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can you save the `this.title` and the `this.link` values into 2 different variables an then call them into php so you can insert the data into a DB?

It's just a simple `YQL` query to search on rss feeds.

After doing the query, I want the results to be saved in a database, but I can't discover how to do that.

Comment: Use ajax to pass the data from jquery to PHP, and do the database insert procedures inside php script.

Comment: I don´t know anything about ajax, can you give me some guidelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand that you are working on a Client-Server architecture.

This means:

- Let's say that this file you are showing us is called "TestYQL.php" (because you did not say the name of it). This file is executed by php (server side), which reads line by line the contents of it, and generates another new file from the original. For educational purposes, let's say the generated file is called "GeneratedTestYQL.html". This file no longer has any php code inside, since it is directly html and js flat. It knows nothing about php. So there are no php functions, variables, nothing. This last file is the one that reaches the client, and the code is executed by a web browser like Chrome, Firefox, etc.

In your case, the file "TestYQL.php" all you have of php is what is inside the `<? Php ....?>` Tags. With php you creates 2 variables, each with a tag inside, but without any purpose since they are not used in any way. So, the generated "GeneratedTestYQL.html" file is the same as the original, but without the lines inside the `<? Php ...?>`.

This means that: The contents of the variables that you use in PHP can be sent to the browser, because with PHP you will generate the file that will be executed in the browser.

Now, when the file "GeneratedTestYQL.html" arrives, the browser starts to show all the contents of the file, it generates the form in which, when you click the button, executes the function *pesquisa()* and now starts javascript (JQuery) bringing data of the feeds, and for the first time, these variables "this.title" and "this.link" begin to exist in javascript.

Since there is no such thing as php here, you can **NOT** access those variables from php.

So, how to save that data in a DB?, well, the common way is to send all the data you want from the browser, to the server, then the server sees what to do with that data. To send data from the browser to the server, you do it by making GET or POST requests to a php file from the server (preferably another file, let's say it will be called "saveFeeds.php").

Data can be sent with a GET request, but it is semantically incorrect since GET means you want to fetch data from the server. So to send that data to the server, you will have to make a POST request from the browser, which is more appropriate.

There are now 2 simple ways to make a POST request. The first and most common of these is from a form in the browser, the other way is using Ajax.

How to do it from a form?

Currently in your code, you have already put a form (That is called "s2"), although currently the same is not necessary, but leave that now.
If you wanted to send the data through a form, you should do 2 things. First and most obvious, create the form; second, the data received from the internet (title and link of feed), send them to the server.

Assuming you fetch data from a single feed per url, and the designated file in charge of receiving the request will be "saveFeeds.php". So, you could create a form like the following after the previous one:

```
<Form class = "sender" action = "saveFeeds.php" method = "post">
  <Input type = "hidden" name = "title" value = ""> <br>
  <Input type = "hidden" name = "link" value = ""> <br>
  <Input type = "submit">
</ Form>
```

Then you need to put the feed data inside the form, because, at this moment, you can't send anything. You could add a function like:

```
Function appendFeedToForm (title, link) {
  Var form = $ (". Sender");
  Form.title.value = title;
  Form.link.value = value;
}
```

And then call it from inside the `$ .each` of the result as
`AppendFeedToForm(this.title, this.link);`

The second case, the easiest way to make a request to the same file using Ajax is with a JQuery shortcut:

```
$.post("saveFeeds.php", r.item);
```

If you are interested in validations, you can take a look at the JQuery documentation. The important thing about ajax requests is that you can send all the data you want without having to force you to reload the page. Therefore, you can send as many feeds as you want in the same way you would send one.

Now with the data sent from the client to the server, it is necessary to handle the reception of the data. Currently we were pointing all the data to the file "saveFeeds.php", so, now, finally we can put the content from javascript. To access them, simply in that file, you should check the fields:

```
$ _POST ['title']     // This names are from input names of form
$ _POST ['link']      // or properties sended through Ajax
```

So, here, you have tp prepare the connection to your database and save those parameters. Currently you did not mention which database engine you are using, so, for this moment, I'll shorten the answer here.

Note: I was not giving you the best practices to solve your problem, but rather the minimum necessary.